# Example of trickiness of finite lattice representation problem?

Tags: lo.logic, order-theory, examples, universal-algebra, lattice-theory

I'm trying to come up with a good explanation for my students of why the [finite lattice representation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_lattice_representation_problem) is difficult. I've already shown that the "greedy approach" to representing the lattice drawn in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85724/given-a-lattice-l-with-n-elements-are-there-finite-groups-h-g-such-that-l-c) as the congruence lattice on a finite algebra - namely, realize the lattice as a sublattice of a lattice of partitions on some large enough finite set $X$, and then look at the algebra on $X$ given by all functions respecting each partition in that sublattice - breaks down.

I'd now like to explain why this *doesn't* lead to an easy *negative* solution. Towards that end:

> Is there a not-too-hard-to-verify example of a bounded lattice $L$ such that
>
> - $L$ is isomorphic to the congruence lattice of some finite algebra, but
> - the smallest $n$ such that $L$ embeds into the bounded lattice of partitions of $\{1,...,n\}$ is strictly less than the smallest size of an algebra with congruence lattice $\cong L$?

Essentially, a concrete example of this would give a convincing argument that the failure of the greedy strategy doesn't actually tell us much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$M_4$, the modular lattice of height two with four atoms is an example.

$M_4$ arises as the subgroup lattice of the symmetric group on $3$ letters, hence it arises as the congruence lattice of a regular $S_3$-set. This is an algebra with $6$ elements. There is no representation of $M_4$ as the congruence lattice of a finite algebra $\mathbf{A}$ where $\mathbf{A}$ has fewer than $6$ elements. This is proved in

[A minimal congruence lattice representation for $M_{p+1}$](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/abs/minimal-congruence-lattice-representation-for-mathbbmp1/F1031B09770B7060128554C0A2E86EB5)
Roger Bunn, David Grow, Matt Insall, Philip Thiem
J. Aust. Math. Soc. 108 (2020), 332-340

Their main result is that if $p$ is an odd prime, then a minimal congruence lattice representation of $M_{p+1}$ has size $2p$, so a minimal congruence lattice representation of $M_4 = M_{3+1}$ has size $2\cdot 3 = 6$.
A few years ago I posted [a shorter proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.04784) of the Bunn-Grow-Insall-Thiem theorem to the arxiv.

On the other hand, it is possible to embed $M_4$ into the lattice of partitions of a $5$-element set, and $5<6$. The following four partitions of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ generate such an $M_4$:

12/34/5
13/25/4
14/35/2
15/24/3

Comment: Lovely, thank you!

Comment: Somewhat-follow-up question: is there a sequence $(L_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of lattices such that $(i)$ each $L_i$ is isomorphic to the congruence lattice of a finite algebra but $(ii)$ the function $i\mapsto f(i)$ sending $i$ to the smallest size of an algebra with congruence lattice $\cong L_i$ is (say) super-polynomial?

Comment: I don't know. There aren't many results which tell you, given $L$,  the size of the smallest algebra $A$ with $\textrm{Con}(A)\cong L$.

Comment: I've asked a follow-up question about this (also, my original comment was botched - of course the point is that the size of the algebra should be compared to the size of the lattice).